# How do I convert an image from a NodeJS Buffer object to base64 in JavaScript so it can be used in the <img> src attribute?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image

I am trying to retrieve an images I have stores on my database in a Buffer format to my front end and display them as real images. I know this is possible and that I have the right data as explained at the end.

Backend NodeJS & Express (mongodb database):

```
router.get("/get-reviews", async (req, res) => {
  const review = await Review.find() // Getting all my reviews from my database.

  console.log(review[0].img); // Below is my img object where you can see it is in a Buffer format of some sort.
  /*
  img: {
    data: new Binary(Buffer.from("52494646e42300005745425056503820d8230000d018019d012a...", "hex"), 0),
    contentType: 'image/webp'
  }
  */

  res.json({ test_img: review[0].img });
});
```

Frontend Javascript:

```
async function displayTestImg() {
  const data = await fetch("/get-reviews").then(res => res.json())

  console.log(data); // Below is what I am retriving from my server, still some buffer format but looks a little different for some reason
  /* 
  contentType: "image/webp"
  data:
    data: (9196) [82, 73, 70, 70, 228, 35, 0, 0, 87, 69, 66, 80, 86, 80, 56, 32, …]
    type: "Buffer"
  */

  document.getElementById("my_container_element").innerHTML = `
    <img src="data:${ test_img.contentType };base64,${ test_img.data.toString('base64') }">
  `;
  // Here I am getting the error: GET data:image/webp;base64,[object Object] net::ERR_INVALID_URL

  document.getElementById("my_container_element").innerHTML = `
    <img src="data:${ test_img.contentType };base64,${ test_img.data.data.toString('base64') }">
  `;
  // Here I am getting the error: GET data:image/webp;base64,82,73,70,70,228,35,0,0,87,69,66,80,86... net::ERR_INVALID_URL

} displayTestImg();
```

As you can see both of the things I have tried is giving me errors. This is confusing to be because when I send the data through `res.render("index", { test_img: reviews[0].img });` and load it in through EJS like this: `<img src="data:<%= review.img.contentType %>;base64,<%= review.img.data.toString('base64') %>" alt="">`, then it works perfectly fine! However, I need to load it in through JavaScript so how can I acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so finally I found an answer:

The [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) object only exists in NodejS so when I tried to use `.toString('base64')` on it, it only returned the actual object as a string instead of converting it.

The solution I found is this function:

```js
function toBase64(arr) {
  return window.btoa(arr.reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), ''));
}
```

So all I had to do was type the following and it worked!

```js
document.getElementById("my_container_element").innerHTML = `
  <img src="data:${ test_img.contentType };base64,${ toBase64(test_img.data.data) }">
`;
```